# How do I get the minutes?

Tags: php

I have a big problem for getting/computing the minutes.

Scenario:

I have a form which is the user can input the seconds [5s, 10s, 25s, 30s, 60s]. I called the table *"Duration"*

I already have *"Duration"* [compose of minutes:seconds], in my database which is ***"1:5"*** [the last input]. Then I insert again another seconds ***"10s"***...

*the format is ***minutes:seconds***

The correct output should be: **1:15**

The current result is : **0:15**

AS we see. I have a problem in computing the minutes. The codes I will show is good for subtracting the seconds. But now I need to revised it to adding the seconds.

Here's my code:

```
$duration = $_POST["duration"];

if(sizeof($bldg) == 1)
{
$total = sizeof($bldg)-1;
}
else
{
$total = sizeof($bldg)%2;
}

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($bldg);$i++)
{
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT fldTotalDuration FROM tbldata  WHERE  fldNetname = '".$network."' AND fldBldgName = '".$bldg[$i]."'  AND  fldWeek = '".$week."' AND fldMonth = '".$month."' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
{
$totalduration = "";
$seconds = 0;
$minutes = 0;

$computeSecMin = $seconds * $minutes; 
$subSecMin = $computeSecMin + $duration; 
$getMin = floor($subSecMin/60); 
$getSec = $subSecMin%60;
$totalduration = $getMin .":". $getSec; 
}
else{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$time = explode(":",$row['fldTotalDuration']);
$dur = explode(" ",$duration);

$computeSecMin = 60 * $time[0]; 
$subSecMin = $computeSecMin + $time[1] + $dur[0];
$getMin = floor($subSecMin/60); 
$getSec = $subSecMin%60; 
$totalduration = $getMin .":". $getSec; 
  }     
}

        $query = "INSERT INTO tbldata(fldNetname,fldBldgName,fldPlaylist,fldMonth,fldWeek,fldDuration,fldFrom,fldTo,fldTotalDuration) VALUES ('".$network."','".$bldg[$i]."','".$AdName."','".$month."','".$week."','".$duration."','".$from."','".$to."', '".$totalduration."')";
        mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

$duration = is came from another form where its a combobox/dropdown that is consists of 5s, 10s, 25s, 30s, 60s.

Currently, for adding the seconds is okay but for minutes is not good.

my problem for the computation is this ***"$getMin = floor($subSecMin/60); "*** .The result of this is ***"0"*** but it should be ***"1"*** because this computation is for *"minutes"*.

Thanks for helping me with this problem.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` of `$time` and `$dur` and tell us the result?

Comment: @DanielX2010....here's the result for your request. array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "5" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "s" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you got is what you should get.
If

```
$time = [0, 5]
```

and

```
$dur = [10, s]
```

then

```
$computeSecMin = 60 * $time[0] = 60*0 = 0
```

and

```
$subSecMin = $computeSecMin + $time[1] + $dur[0] = 0 + 5 + 10 = 15
```

Thus

```
$getMin = floor($subSecMin/60) = floor(15/60) = floor(0.25) = 0
```

It seems to me that you are computing it right, and the result is indeed 0 minutes.
The problem is your duration variable. It seems to me that your program is getting the wrong value. If I understand, it should be `[1, 5]` and not `[0,5]`. Check the function that is getting this value.

Comment: @DanielX2010....thats correct... i don't know how to revised the $getMin. so it will not become 0...

Comment: @PrincessToledo How are you getting the duration variable? from a database? From what I can see, you are not getting it correctly. Try posting how you get it. We might find the problem

Comment: @PrincessToledo since the error is coming from the duration variable, you should check the `$_POST["duration"]`. That is the origin of the error. Check the page/script that is sending this variable.
BTW:avoid doing querries like that. It is deprecated and vulnerable to SQL injection. Use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: @DanielX2010...why the error is $_POST["duration"] its okay, this one will just get the seconds that user click....I think I just need to revised this one "$getMin = floor($subSecMin/60)" so it will become correct. And I dont know how to revised this one...

Comment: @PrincessToledo You said in you question that your duration value is `1:5` but you said that your `var_dump` of your `$time` variable is   `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "5" }`. That means that this variable is `0:5` and not `1:5` as you wanted it to be. I assume you are not getting the right value. Check your database to see if you really have `1:5` as value or if your query is getting the right line, because you are definitely not getting `1:5`

Comment: @DanielX2010..yeh I already found the error...and its because of my query... and also thanks for helping me..

Comment: @PrincessToledo np. I'm glad you found it :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are trying to do (sorry, I changed variables names, yours were not obvious):

```
$time = array(1,5);
$time_plus = '10s';

$time_plus = preg_replace('#\D#', '', $time_plus);
$minutes = $time [0] + (($time_plus + $time[1] >= 60) ? 1 : 0);
$seconds = ($time[1] + $time_plus) % 60;

echo $new_time = $minutes . ":" . $seconds;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/eOBNeHrq

Comment: @NabilKadimi.. how can I change the $time to not an array version??

Answer (score 0):

You may find using mysql for time manipulations will be cleaner for your application. AddTime() lets you do what you want with only seconds and minutes.

SELECT ADDTIME('00:32.50','1:27.50');

gives the result of:

01:59:01.000000

So, this adds 32.5 seconds to 1 minute 27.50 seconds = 1 minutes 59 seconds and .01 milliseconds.